# DropdownButton in Flutter not changing values to the selected value

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

In my code I added a dropdown which looks like below, When I switched the selection in dropdown its not getting updated its showing exception, I have  declared a variable in statefull widget , In  my dropdown function I am assigning that as A value to the dropdown Button, and in Onchanged I am passing the json to another function there I am taking the value from a variable and assigning it to a opSelected variable inside the setState

```
class _ReportFilterState extends State<ReportFilter> {

  String opSelected;
 //declared string to hold the selected value in dropdown within the state class.

    buildMainDropdown(List<Map<String, Object>> items, StateSetter setState) {
        return Container(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 27.0,
              vertical: 16.0,
            ),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: DropdownButton(
                  isExpanded: true,
                  hint: Text("Choose Filters"),
                  value: opSelected, // Here assigning the value 
                  items: items
                      .map((json) => DropdownMenuItem(
                          child: Text(json["displayName"]), value: json))
                      .toList(),
                  onChanged: (json) {
                    manageIntState(json, setState);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

 void manageIntState(Map<String, Object> jsonSelected, StateSetter setState) {
    setState(() {
      dispName = jsonSelected["displayName"]; 

//here I am setting the selected value
      opSelected = dispName;

//Doing some operations
      id = jsonSelected['id'];
      type = jsonSelected['type'];
      selectedFilterOption = jsonSelected;

      if (jsonSelected.containsKey("data")) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> tempList;
        List<String> dailogContent = List<String>();
        tempList = jsonSelected['data'];

        tempList
            .map((val) => {
                  dailogContent.add(val['displayId']),
                })
            .toList();
        _showReportDialog(dailogContent);
      }
    });
  }
```

But when I run I will end up with error

> items==null||
>   items.isEmpty||value==null||itsems.where((DropdownMenuItem
>   item)=>item.value==value).length==1 is not true ..

Let me know what I have done wrong in code so its giving me like this, if I commented its not showing the selected dropdown value.

Answer (score 0):

That error happens when the selected `value` of the `DropdownButton` is not one of the values of it's items.

In your case, your items values are `json` which is a `Map<String, Object>`, and the value of the `DropdownButton` is `opSelected` which is a `String`.

So you need to change the type of `opSelected` like this:

```
Map<String, Object> opSelected;
```

Also make sure you are passing a reference of the same list of items to `buildMainDropdown()`, because if you are creating a new list while calling `buildMainDropdown()` then the `DropdownButton` will have another reference of options and it's not allowed

---

**Note:** you may want yo use dynamic instead of Object for the Map, like this:

```
Map<String, dynamic> opSelected;
```

Here is why: [What is the difference between dynamic and Object in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257735/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-object-in-dart#31264980)

Comment: Hi, okay, I have added a print for opSelected  inside the manageIntState there  opSelected getting the selected value but its not going to update in the dropdown, Do you have any idea  what I have to change? and in  buildMainDropdown currently I am passing a hardcoded value

Comment: How are you calling buildMainDropdown()?

Comment: like this   createBox(BuildContext context, List<Map<String, Object>> val,
      StateSetter setState) {  buildMainDropdown(val, setState) }

Comment: and how are you calling createBox() ? I'm asking to see how you pass the list

Comment: inside  DropdownMenuItem( child: Text(json["displayName"]), value: json))                 .toList(), here for value I am setting the MAP value, instead of that I gave json['displayName '] then  its working fine, but I am not passing the map to the onchanged i.e manageIntState()

Comment: since I passed the Json its giving errors for value, but after changing that its showing the selected value, dont know why this behavior

Comment: you have to pass the json as value and the opSelected should be a Map too, because the items would be a Map. Also make sure you are passing a reference of the same list of items to buildMainDropdown(), because if you are creating a new list while calling buildMainDropdown() then the DropdownButton will have another reference of options and it's not allowed

Comment: how opselected going to be a map? if possible can you add that code? thanks

Comment: Okay Thanks for the answer, I will follow those steps :)