# Understanding dynamic property of Async/Await in Flutter

Tags: flutter, async-await

I'm new to flutter and learning through a tutorial about Flutter. I am learning from done projects so sometimes I am not understanding something on codes. An example, I understood below codes but just I didn't understand this line ==>
**`dynamic result = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/location');`**
I was checking that **dynamic** property but I couldn't find any information about it. Why that project was used **await** wit ***dynamic*** property ( What's mean of **dynamic** property?)

```
FlatButton.icon(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          dynamic result = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/location');
                          setState(() {
                            print("result $result");
                            data={
                              'time' : result['time'],
                              'location':result['location'],
                              'isDaytime':result['isDaytime'],
                              'flag':result['flag'],
                            };
                          });
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.edit_location,
                          color: Colors.green[100],
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          "Edit Location",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey[200],
                          ),
                        )),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between dynamic and Object in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257735/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-object-in-dart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous function that is passed to the `onPressed()` is marked as *async* because it has asynchronous code, i.e. this line of code:

```
dynamic result = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/location');
```

Basically it means that the result of this operation is not returned immediately but it takes some time to be done.

`Navigator.pushNamed()` opens new page (in this example the page that is registered under '/location' path) and can return some data using `Future` when an user will close this page. With `await` keyword you can wait for that data which is next assign to the `result` variable. Without `await` you would assign `Future` instead.

Method `pushNamed()` is prepared to return data with any type. `dynamic` is a general data type so it can accept numeric value, strings, list etc. However, you as a developer can (if you want to) set data type of `result` variable explicitly by casting return value of `pushNamed()`. So, assuming returned data is of type `Map<String, Object>`, you can refactor above line of code to:

```
Map<String, Object> result = (await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/location')) as Map<String, Object>;
```

For more information about returning value from a screen visit this [page](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data).

Answer (score 1):

`Async/Await` is explained by other answers, so let's see the `dynamic` keyword.

`int x;` means the value stored in x can only be an integer and not anything else.
Now `x = 1.0;` is not possible.

---

`var b = 2.0;` is a little different, here the type is implied to be `double` and is equivalent to `double b = 2.0` or `double b = 2`.

So `b = true` is not possible, but `b = 1;` will work as it will be stored as `1.0(double)` and not `1(int)`.

---

Coming to `dynamic`, it means the type is not fixed and can change.

So,
`dynamic x = 1;` and then

`x = 2.0;` will not cause error.

---

Now, for the code `dynamic result = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/location');`
*This means when we return from the new page then the result can have and any type and is not fixed.*

However, let say the new page is guaranteed to return either `true` or `false` i.e. boolean only values then you can also write

```
bool result = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/location');
```