# Why I can't refer to a key in an object's another key?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

Why I cant refer to a key in an object that is already placed in **another object's key** while mapping like this:

```
var object = {
  "allStudents": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "hobbies": {
        "sport": "Football",
        "music": "Piano"
      } ,
    },
    {
      "name": "Julyo",
      "hobbies": {
        "sport": "Vollyball",
        "music": "Guitar"
      } ,
    },
  ],
};

class Student {
  String name;
  dynamic hobbies;
  Student({this.name, this.hobbies});
}

class Hobbies {
  String sport;
  String music;
  Hobbies({this.sport, this.music});
}

List<Student> studentsList = [];

void getStudentsList () {
  studentsList = object["allStudents"].map((stu)=>
  Student(
    name: stu["name"] ,
    hobbies: Hobbies(
      sport: stu['hobbies']['sport'] ,
        music:stu['hobbies']['music'],
    ) ,
  )
  ).toList();
}
```

everything is working very well until I add the second operator **['sport']** or **['music']**  as the IDE keeps telling me:

> The operator '[]' is not defined for the class 'Object'.
>   Try defining the operator '[]'.

see screenshot: 
[can't refer to a key's value in another object's key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CoUE.png)

Comment: try changing the single quotes ' to double quotes " ?

Comment: It didnt work, I don't think that the quotes are part of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart is not aware of what your structure is like, therefore, you have to make it aware by providing a cast.

```
void getStudentsList () {
  studentsList = (object["allStudents"] as List<Map<String,dynamic>>)
      .map((stu)=>
  Student(
    name: stu["name"] ,
    hobbies: Hobbies(
      sport: stu['hobbies']['sport'] ,
        music:stu['hobbies']['music'],
    ) ,
  )
  ).toList();
}
```

I tried it on this dartPad draft and this worked..
https://dartpad.dev/b338f2a46bcb361de5e05c5ea6b8c74f

Answer (score 3):

That's because your `var object` is of type `Map<String,Object>`, and when you access the using first **[]**, you have `Object` as a return, soon Object is not a map or iterable, the second [] canot be aplied. You have to explicit tells that your `object` is of type `Map<String, dynamic>`, like example below:

```
Map<String, dynamic> object = {
  "allStudents": [
    {
      "name": "John",
      "hobbies": {"sport": "Football", "music": "Piano"},
    },
    {
      "name": "Julyo",
      "hobbies": {"sport": "Vollyball", "music": "Guitar"},
    },
  ],
};
```

and **change your parse code to explicit map to work with second []:**

```
void getStudentsList() {
    final test = (object["allStudents"] as List)
        .map<Student>(
          (stu) => Student(
            name: stu["name"],
            hobbies: Hobbies(
              sport: stu['hobbies']['sport'],
              music: stu['hobbies']['music'],
            ),
          ),
        )
        .toList();

    print(test);
  }
```

Now it works!

**Note:** Dynamic can be every possible value type, diferent of `Object` type, for more info, see the discussion [What is the difference between dynamic and Object in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257735/what-is-the-difference-between-dynamic-and-object-in-dart/31278271)

Comment: Thank you it does work now and I got it. I prefer putting the map type (Map<String, dynamic>) after (as List) because these data will be fetched from a JSON format.